# How to import in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Every time I try to import into my nodejs file I get the error, cannot import outside a module

I have tried multiple solutions on StackOverFlow such as adding

```
"type":"module"
```

and setting file extensions to .mjs

I want to import constants from a different file but I am not sure how to

example

Constants.js

```
export const help1 = 5
export const help2 = 6
export const help3 = 7
```

backend.js

```
import {help1,help2,help3} from './constants.js'
```

How should I import them?

Comment: use commonJs import/export in Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code. `Object.freeze` will not allow any change in object properties.

Constants.js

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    HELP1: 5,
    HELP2: 6,
    HELP3: 7
});
```

backend.js

```
var constants = require('./constants');

console.log(constants.HELP1); // 5
```